# What kind of filters might have been applied to these photos?

Tags: photo-editing, color, reverse-engineering

Neither of these is mine (obviously, since I'm asking), but I see both effects quite frequently as of late. I'm trying to figure out the nature of them.

Can anyone make a guess as to what kind of filters / adjustments are at work here with regards to the colors?

DEAD LINK: http://wallbase.cc/wallpaper/2639034

DEAD LINK: http://wallbase.cc/wallpaper/1861194

Comment: Please refer to [this post on meta.](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/q/3881/9161)

Comment: They're both examples of desaturation and cross processing, put those terms in to google and see what comes up!

Comment: @Kir: Links are dead. Please post your photos here, fix the links or get this question quickly closed.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing fancy on these pictures. Both are shallow DOF, but that is not a filter. First one has a lens flare, most probably not filter either.

The first photo has lower color temperature, that makes it having a yellow tint. I would use Photoshop curves (separately, RGB) to create this yellow tinting. Also, black point is raised, and consequently the overal contrast is a bit lowered.

The second photo might as well be unedited. Looks mostly duocolor, but I do not see this being the result of a filter. The yellows and the bluish browns look natural. Maybe the author emphasized yellows a bit, and added a purple or blue cast, but very little. This I would do in Photoshop as well. Create one layer, use Curves, create the dark version of the image. Create another layer, use Curves, create the yellowish version of the image (lamp, light casts, etc). Then just use masks and create transparencies to mix this two layers. But again, the second photo could just as well be an unedited one.